# About vertical and horizontal view in Balkan Graph Orgchart

Tags: orgchart

I am testing the api for organization charts and I have not found any way to create the display of the nodes vertically and horizontally, is it possible to do this?

Has an example:

[image: sample]

Sorry for my English

Thanks in advance!
Rogerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

you can achieve requested functionality by setting **layout: BALKANGraph.mixed** option

Go to the [Layout](https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Docs/Layout) documentation page